# I cannot get black to work on a Mac, using visual studio code in the terminal using a makefile

Tags: python, pep, pycodestyle

I wanted to try using black, the python code formatter, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I have a virtual environment created using the following:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

I then install black:

```
pip install black
```

I try running black using the following commands, but it does not change anything:

```
black ./python/
    
python -m black ./python/ 

black -l 60 ./python/
```

I am using black within visual studio code and I am using the following requirements file:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
black==20.8b1
click==7.1.2
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
pathspec==0.8.1
regex==2020.11.13
toml==0.10.2
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
```

I checked the following page to see if they had any indication about which version worked, but they are all listed with pre-release:

```
https://pypi.org/project/black/#history
```

I have tried 3 old versions of the repository (20, 19, 18) and it doesn't work.   Any idea about how I get this to work.   I am on a Mac, using visual studio code and running a make file in the terminal ?

Comment: The terminal you're running the code in, where is it's current working directory? You might have to cd into the folder you want to format then try `black filename.py`.  Also, if you  run `black --version` is there an output?